# Deserialize POJOs from multiple YAML documents in a single file in Jackson

Tags: java, jackson, yaml

I have a YAML file that looks something like this:

```
---
name: Sam
tags:
    -   Dev
    -   Java
----
name: Bob
tags:
    -   PM
```

I'd like to use Jackson to deserialize all documents from the file, but I don't see a way to use a normal `ObjectMapper` to do it. <del>If I use the `YAMLFactory` to create a parser for my file I can step through all tokens, so the parser is obviously capable of dealing with multiple documents - but how do I tie them together?</del> Looks like the parser created by my YAMLFactory only parses a single document out of the file.

I've also tried creating a YAMLParser directly and using `ObjectMapper#readValue(JsonParser, Class)`, but the ObjectMapper exhausts the entire YAMLParser to deserialize a single instance.

Comment: This does not look like it is well supported. You probably notice this already - https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformat-yaml/blob/master/src/main/java/com/fasterxml/jackson/dataformat/yaml/YAMLParser.java#L401

Comment: Ah, I hadn't seen that. Looks like there's a bug somewhere else in the code, then: the comment on consuming `DocumentEnd` says `do NOT close`, which seems like it ought to terminate parsing, leaving the stream open, and I ought to be able to apply a new object read operation to the stream at that point. )c: Thanks for pointing that out. Want to change your comment to an answer so I can accept?

Comment: I have posted an answer with a sample code and the exception stack trace. I think it might be useful.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

This is years later but it's worth pointing out that this is supported.
The Jackson semantics are slightly different, probably due to it's JSON origins. This can be achieved by using the [`MappingIterator`](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformats-text/issues/66#issuecomment-357794557) from `ObjectMapper`.

```
YAMLFactory yamlFactory;
ObjectMapper mapper;

YAMLParser yamlParser = yamlFactory.createParser("file-with-multiple-docs.yaml")
List<ObjectNode> docs = mapper
      .readValues(yamlParser, new TypeReference<ObjectNode>(){})
      .readAll();
```

Replace `ObjectNode` with your own POJOs if desired.

Comment: Nice! That's exactly what I wanted when I asked the question, though I regret to say that it's no longer useful to me as I mostly don't work in Java these days. I've unaccepted the previous answer to accept yours instead -- hopefully that'll help anyone who shows up here find the right way forward.

Comment: Thanks for answering even though this was years later, and thanks Dathan for accepting, because only a few weeks later this has already helped me out. :)

Comment: Note that this feature is not yet properly documented: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformats-text/issues/133

Comment: I feel the SnakeYaml metioned below is a better solution to load multiple documentations. However, if you prefer to use the Jackson lib, the solution here can help, but not very clear. The key point here is to concat multiple yaml files into a sequence (string or inputStream, but must be a valid yaml format) to create the yamlParser. The mappingIterator may help, but not necessary. 
``` final SequenceInputStream sis = new SequenceInputStream(is1, is2);
        final InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(sis);
        final YAMLParser yamlParser = yamlFactory.createParser(isr);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use directly SnakeYaml (Jackson YAML parser is using it internally):

```
try (InputStream input = new FileInputStream(file)) {
    Yaml yaml = new Yaml(new SafeConstructor());
    yaml.loadAll(input).forEach( System.out::println );
} catch (Throwable e) {
    System.out.println("ERROR: " + e.getMessage());
}
```

Will Produce:

```
{name=Sam, tags=[Dev, Java]}
{name=Bob, tags=[PM]}
```

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately I've moved on from that project (and to a new job where I don't use Java at all, so far), so I can't use this. But it is exactly what I wanted.

Comment: Your question is first when you ask google about reading multiple documents by Jackson. This problem is still valid, hope it will help somebody else ;-).

Comment: Yep - and that's exactly why I un-accepted the previously-accepted answer and accepted yours, so it'll show up first. Yay for curation!

Answer (score 1):

This does not seem to be supported at this point. Here is the link to [the YAMLParser source code](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformat-yaml/blob/master/src/main/java/com/fasterxml/jackson/dataformat/yaml/YAMLParser.java#L401).

If the input YAML contains several documents then Jackson fails. Here is an example:

```
public class JacksonYAML {
    public static final String YAML = "---\n" +
            "name: Sam\n" +
            "tags:\n" +
            "    -   Dev\n" +
            "    -   Java\n" +
            "----\n" +
            "name: Bob\n" +
            "tags:\n" +
            "    -   PM";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(new YAMLFactory());
        System.out.println(mapper.readValue(YAML, Object.class));
    }
}
```

The exception error points to the second item in the input source:

```
Exception in thread "main" while scanning a simple key
 in 'reader', line 6, column 1:
    ----
    ^
could not found expected ':'
 in 'reader', line 7, column 1:
    name: Bob
    ^

    at com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.yaml.snakeyaml.scanner.ScannerImpl.stalePossibleSimpleKeys(ScannerImpl.java:465)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.yaml.snakeyaml.scanner.ScannerImpl.needMoreTokens(ScannerImpl.java:280)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.yaml.snakeyaml.scanner.ScannerImpl.checkToken(ScannerImpl.java:225)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.yaml.snakeyaml.parser.ParserImpl$ParseBlockSequenceEntry.produce(ParserImpl.java:502)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.yaml.snakeyaml.parser.ParserImpl.peekEvent(ParserImpl.java:158)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.yaml.snakeyaml.parser.ParserImpl.getEvent(ParserImpl.java:168)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.yaml.YAMLParser.nextToken(YAMLParser.java:331)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.UntypedObjectDeserializer$Vanilla.mapArray(UntypedObjectDeserializer.java:529)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.UntypedObjectDeserializer$Vanilla.deserialize(UntypedObjectDeserializer.java:449)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.UntypedObjectDeserializer$Vanilla.mapObject(UntypedObjectDeserializer.java:572)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.UntypedObjectDeserializer$Vanilla.deserialize(UntypedObjectDeserializer.java:435)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:3051)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2146)
    at stackoverflow.JacksonYAML.main(JacksonYAML.java:26)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
```

Comment: The document separator is "---", not four dashes: http://yaml.org/spec/1.0/#ns-ns-document-start